# System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path from remote server

Tags: c#, umbraco7

I'm allowing a user to upload an excel file which has a path to images. The problem is it's throwing the following error:

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the
>   path 'C:\Users\gwphi_000\Desktop\test\OrderEmail.png'. at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at
>   System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>   at System.IO.File.InternalReadAllBytes(String path, Boolean checkHost)
>   at UploadExelFiles.Helpers.GetExcelDataFromFile.ReadExcelFile(String
>   pathToMedia)

In IIS I have changed the app pool to Network Services and on my local testing machine that works ok, but when on the remote server it throws the error.

My code is

```
foreach (var item in excelList)
{
    string fileName             = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var content                 = contentService.CreateContent(item.Product, allEventsNode.Id, "accessorieItems");
    IMediaService mediaService  = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MediaService;
    var newImage                = mediaService.CreateMedia($"{fileName}.jpeg", -1, "Image");
    byte[] buffer               = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.GetFullPath(item.ProductUrl));
    MemoryStream strm           = new MemoryStream(buffer);

    newImage.SetValue("umbracoFile", $"{fileName}.jpeg", strm);
    mediaService.Save(newImage);

    var umbracoHelper   = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);
    var image           = umbracoHelper.Media(newImage.Id).Url;
    string imagePath    = image.ToString();

    content.SetValue("productId", item.ProductId);
    content.SetValue("productTitle", item.Product);
    content.SetValue("productPrice", item.Price);
    content.SetValue("productImage", imagePath);
    content.SetValue("productDescription", item.ProductDescription);
    contentService.SaveAndPublishWithStatus(content);
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example of excel file data?

Comment: You're trying to get access to user's file system from server that's why you probably have this error. Locally it allows you cause it's local server but remote machine can't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else ever needs to upload an excel file which has paths to images, I have published how I have done it.

The main point is what 'Gabriel Luci' wrote, the path looks for the images on the server, I'll blame it on me for being tired to not think about that.

Anyway, the code has now being re-written so that you now have to upload a zip file, within that file is the excel file and images.

The code on how to get the data out of the excel file is below, please NOTE, this is for Umbraco, so you may have to amend it for your own use.

```
public static bool ReadExcelFile(string pathToMedia)
        {
            try
            {
                string filePath                 = pathToMedia;
                string zipFilePath              = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/www/UploadExcelFile");
                string extractImagesTo          = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/www/Images/AccessoriesZipImages");
                string pathToExcelFileOnServer  = string.Empty;



                using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(filePath))
                {
                    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
                    {
                        if (entry.FullName.EndsWith(".xlsx", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||entry.FullName.EndsWith("xls", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(zipFilePath, entry.Name)))
                            {
                                File.Delete(Path.Combine(zipFilePath, entry.Name));
                            }

                            pathToExcelFileOnServer = Path.Combine(zipFilePath, entry.Name);
                            entry.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(zipFilePath, entry.Name));
                        }
                    }
                }


                using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(filePath))
                {
                    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
                    {
                        if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(extractImagesTo, entry.Name)))
                        {
                            File.Delete(Path.Combine(extractImagesTo, entry.Name));
                        }

                        if (entry.FullName.EndsWith(".png", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || entry.FullName.EndsWith(".jpg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            entry.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(extractImagesTo, entry.Name));
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pathToExcelFileOnServer))
                {
                    using (var stream = File.Open(pathToExcelFileOnServer, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
                        {
                            var result = reader.AsDataSet();

                            List<ShoppingCartViewModel> excelList = new List<ShoppingCartViewModel>();

                            foreach (DataTable table in result.Tables)
                            {
                                foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Skip(1)) //Skipping header
                                {
                                    //Cannot seem to use cell names, so use cell location
                                    excelList.Add(new ShoppingCartViewModel(dr[0].ToString(), dr[1].ToString(), dr[2].ToString(), Path.Combine(extractImagesTo, dr[3].ToString()), dr[4].ToString(), null, 0.00, null));
                                }
                            }

                            var contentService  = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.ContentService;
                            var allEventsNode   = ExcelUploadUmbracoAssignedContentHelper.HomePageContent();
                            int rootId          = allEventsNode.Id;
                            var itemsForSale    = contentService.GetChildren(rootId).Where(x => x.ContentType.Alias == "accessorieItems").ToList();

                            //Delete all current nodes                      
                            foreach (var items in itemsForSale)
                            {
                                contentService.Delete(items);
                            }

                            foreach (var item in excelList)
                            {
                                string fileName             = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                                var content                 = contentService.CreateContent(item.Product, allEventsNode.Id,"accessorieItems");
                                IMediaService mediaService  = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MediaService;
                                var newImage                = mediaService.CreateMedia($"{fileName}.jpeg", -1, "Image");
                                byte[] buffer               = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.GetFullPath(item.ProductUrl));
                                MemoryStream strm           = new MemoryStream(buffer);

                                newImage.SetValue("umbracoFile", $"{fileName}.jpeg", strm);
                                mediaService.Save(newImage);

                                var umbracoHelper   = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);
                                var image           = umbracoHelper.Media(newImage.Id).Url;
                                string imagePath    = image.ToString();

                                content.SetValue("productId", item.ProductId);
                                content.SetValue("productTitle", item.Product);
                                content.SetValue("productPrice", item.Price);
                                content.SetValue("productImage", imagePath);
                                content.SetValue("productDescription", item.ProductDescription);
                                contentService.SaveAndPublishWithStatus(content);
                            }

                            contentService.RePublishAll();
                            library.RefreshContent();

                            Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(extractImagesTo), File.Delete);
                            //Delete empty folders in media folder
                            DeleteEmptyFolder.DeleteFolder();
                        }
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It can't find the file either because it doesn't exist, or it doesn't have permissions. You said:

> In IIS I have changed the app pool to Network Services and on my local
>   testing machine

But did you do the same on the server?

Also, remember that when running on the server, it will be looking for the files on the server. Does the path `C:\Users\gwphi_000\Desktop\test\` exist on the server?

Comment: Hi Gabriel, that is the problem, how do I change the path to look on the client's computer. Path is C:\\Users\\gwphi_000\\Desktop\\test\\OrderEmail.png and I completely forgot about that.

Comment: On the server, you know the client's IP address, so you can replace `C:` with `\\[IP]\C$` assuming the administrative `C$` share is enabled in your organization and your firewalls allow it. But then you also have to run it with credentials that have admin rights on the user's machine. There are many parts to it that can break. I'd suggest finding another way to do what you need (run something on the end user's computer directly)